# ¿Cómo personalizar el foreign key de un formulario ? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo los siguientes modelos  Typemovement y WareHoseConcept los cuales están relacionados por una foreign key.  Posteriormente creo un formulario a partir del modelo WareHoseConcept pero cuando renderizo quisiera solo mostrar en el campo typemovement los que tengan la propiedad visible en True.

anexo códigos

**Modelo Typemovement**

```
class TypeMovement (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #usercreated = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.RESTRICT)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Modelo WarehouseConcept**

```
class WareHouseConcept (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    typemovement = models.ForeignKey(TypeMovement, on_delete= models.RESTRICT)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #usercreated = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.RESTRICT)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Creo un formulario a partir del modelo WareHouseConcept

```
class  AddWareHouseConcept (forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddWareHouseConcept, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].required = True, 
        self.fields['typemovement'].required = True,
        self.fields['description'].required = True,
    
    def clean_title(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["title"].upper()
    
    def clean_description(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["description"].upper()

    class Meta:
        model = WareHouseConcept
        fields = ['title','typemovement','description']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'nameValidation'
            }),
            
             'typemovement': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-select',
                'id': 'branchValidation'
            }),
             
                'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'descriptionValidation'
            }), 
        }
```

Al renderizarlo en mi view me muestra la relación WareHouseConcept - Typemovement

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿como podría mostrar el campo typemovements con la propiedad visible en True ?

Gracias